# Delete ActiveRecord associations by single request

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sql-delete

Usually, if we specify `:dependent => :destroy` or `:dependent => :delete` AR call DELETE query for each row of association. If we use `ModelName.delete(batch_of_ids)` AR call single resuest like `DELETE ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN (batch_of_ids)`. Is any possibility to destroy association by single query without definitions own methods? For example something like [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem, but for delete.

Comment: What if you have three models: `A` <- `B` <- `C`, and you want to delete an instance of `A`?

Comment: In case of deep inheritance this task is useless. I'm interesting in simple case, when `MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: I didn't check what happens under the hood but what about `dependent: :delete_all`?

Comment: Great! `dependent: :delete_all` is exactly that I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dependent: :delete_all` to delete all of the records in a single query.